# Why does NIntegrate become much faster if I evaluate a function, then compile it, then make it numerical?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, compile

I am using Mathematica for numerical integrals in optics. By accident, I found out that NIntegrate becomes faster by an order of magnitude for a function I'm integrating, if I take the following steps:

1. `Evaluate[]` the function;
2. `Compile` the function;
3. Define a new function that takes only numerical arguments and applies them to the compiled function.

I haven't been able to reproduce this with other functions; only this one so far. I do know that this integrand is highly oscillatory. Here's my minimal working example:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ClearSystemCache[];

gaussians[x_] :=
  0.1 Sum[
    Exp[-34000. ((2 m)*0.00004)^2]*1/((Pi*0.00001^2)^0.25)*
     Exp[-(x - (2 m)*0.00004)^2/(2*0.00001^2)],
    {m, -200, 200}
    ];
integrand[x_, kx_] := gaussians[x] Exp[-I*kx*x];
numericIntegrand[x_?NumericQ, kx_?NumericQ] := integrand[x, kx]
compiledIntegrand = 
  Compile[{x,kx}, integrand[x, kx]];
numericalCompiledIntegrand[x_?NumericQ, kx_?NumericQ] := 
  compiledIntegrand[x, kx];
compiledEvaluatedIntegrand = 
  Compile[{x, kx}, Evaluate[integrand[x, kx]]];
numericalCompiledEvaluatedIntegrand[x_?NumericQ, kx_?NumericQ] := 
  compiledEvaluatedIntegrand[x, kx];
integral[f_, kx_] := 
  NIntegrate[f[x, kx], {x, -0.008, 0.008}, MaxRecursion -> 15(*,
   AccuracyGoal\[Rule]12,PrecisionGoal\[Rule]9*)];

ParallelTable[TimeConstrained[
  AbsoluteTiming[integral[function, 150000.]],
  60, "Exceeded time limit"
  ],
 {function, {integrand, numericIntegrand, compiledIntegrand, 
   numericalCompiledIntegrand, compiledEvaluatedIntegrand, 
   numericalCompiledEvaluatedIntegrand}}
 ]
```

And the output:

```
CompiledFunction::cfsa :  Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.

CompiledFunction::cfsa :  Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.

NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::slwcon :  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

{{55.2211, -3.03556*10^-6 + 
   2.87568*10^-19 I}, "Exceeded time limit", {53.982, -3.03556*10^-6 \
+ 2.87568*10^-19 I}, "Exceeded time limit", {55.0044, -3.03556*10^-6 \
+ 2.87568*10^-19 I}, {4.56948, -3.03556*10^-6 + 2.87568*10^-19 I}}
```

As you can see from the table output, only this specific sequence of steps gives the speedup I'm referring to. `integrand` takes the integrand as is, `numericIntegrand` uses a "numerical" version of the integrand (i.e. one that takes only numerical values), `compiledIntegrand` uses a compiled version of the integrand, `numericalCompiledIntegrand` uses a numerical version of the compiled integrand, `compiledEvaluatedIntegrand` uses a compiled version of the integrand with `Evaluate[]` applied before compilation, and finally, `numericalCompiledEvaluatedIntegrand` applies the steps I outlined above. All of them take over 50 seconds, except for `numericalCompiledEvaluatedIntegrand`, which takes less than 5 seconds. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: If you evaluate ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[compiledIntegrand]`` you will see `MainEvaluate[ Hold[integrand][ R0, R1]]` which means that the integrand is not correctly compiled withour `Evaluate`. This is why you cannot get any speed-up from that.

Comment: When I evaluate that command, I get CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[CompiledFunction[Argument count: 2
Argument types: {_Real,_Real}

]].

Doesn't that mean it is evaluated in my version (12.1.1.0, Student Edition, 64-bit Windows)?

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Try to execute `Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]` before you call ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint``.

Comment: If you use [immediate instead of delayed assignments](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html), a few of your issues will go away already.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That does it (should be ``Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]``, but the markup language messed up the command, so you need to put two backticks before and two after the code). Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for `Evaluate` is that `Compile` is surprisingly bad at recognizing the expression that it is suppose to optimize. One can use `Evaluate` as a workaround, but I prefer to use `With` as follows (`Block` is supposed to shield `x` and `kx` from external definitions):

```
cf = Block[{x, kx},
   With[{code = integrand[x, kx]},
    Compile[{{x, _Real}, {kx, _Real}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C"
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

The above also uses `CompilationTarget -> "C"` which will attempt to compile the code if your system has a C compiler installed. That will make the execution even faster.

Now we wrap the compiled code by a "numeric" function:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, kx_?NumericQ] := compiledEvaluatedIntegrand[x, kx];
```

The point of this is that `NIntegrate` attempts to analyze every analytic input to figure out which integration strategy is the most promising and to compile the expression if possible. For some reason, it does not realize that we have compiled our function already and needlessly inserts symbolic values into it which kicks off a cascade of error messages. The pattern `_?NumericQ` just prevents this symbolic evaluation pass.

Finally we can do the integration. Since the integrand is highly oscillatory, `"LocalAdaptive"` is quite a reasonable choice for the integration method.

```
kx = 150000.;
NIntegrate[f[x, kx], {x, -0.008, 0.008}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

On my machine, this is more then 4 times faster than `numericalCompiledEvaluatedIntegrand` with `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` and 13 times faster then `numericalCompiledEvaluatedIntegrand` without `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"`.

**Edit**

Just to point out the commentbelow by Michael E2: The following combination makes the use of the pattern `_?NumericQ` obsolete:

```
cf2 = Block[{x, kx},
   With[{code = integrand[x, kx]},
    Compile[{{x, _Real}, {kx, _Real}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
     ]
    ]
   ];
NIntegrate[cf2[x, kx], {x, -0.008, 0.008}, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

And it is even another 20% faster!

Comment: You can also make a compiled function be "numeric" with `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`.

Comment: Hm. I have just tried that but `NIntegrate` still throws two(!) errors "CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument -x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.". =/

Comment: Odd that `cf[-x, 150000.]` gives that message but `cf[x, 150000.]` does not. `Nintegrate` is checking symmetry.  With `Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`, which makes sense for a compiled function, the message goes away.

Comment: Ah! Great! I had tried `"SymbolicProcessing" -> False` before but to no avail. It seems to work only in combination with `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`.

Comment: Don't you think the message with `cf2[-x, 150000.]` is a bug? I can't quite figure out the pattern. I thought it was the `-1` factor in `Times[-1, x]`. But I get the error for `cf2[Exp[x], 150000.]` but not for `cf2[Sin[x], 150000.]`. Maybe the trigger is whether the head is `Plus`, `Times`, or `Power`.  Apparently, it is not using `NumericQ`.

Comment: Not sure. I tend to think so.